# Owl-carousel need scroll effect on navigation hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

This is the code for my owl-carousel.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
     navigation: true,
     pagination: false,
     lazyLoad: true
    });
 });
```

I need to scroll the carousel slowly, when I hover on the "prev" or "next' buttons.

Is anyone know how to do this?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/245/)

Answer (score 2):

Add this JS

```
  navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
      "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
      ],
```

Your complete JS should look like this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        navigation: true,
        pagination: false,
        lazyLoad: true,
          
    });
  
   $(".owl-inner").hover(function() {
     $(".owl-prev").show();
     $(".owl-next").show();
 }, function() {
     $(".owl-prev").hide();
     $(".owl-next").hide();
 });
 $(".owl-prev").hide();
 $(".owl-next").hide();
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
     margin:0px 50px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
    padding: 0px 2px
}


.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  position: absolute;
}
 
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev{
  left: 0px;
  top: 55px; 
}
 
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next{
  right: -45px;
  top: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="owl-inner">
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
        <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Reference**](http://codepen.io/OwlFonk/pen/qhgjb/)

Comment: I need scroll the carosal,when i hover on that buttons

Comment: You can simply hide or show `prev-next` button on `hover` and `hover-out` of particular `div`